# How to add a timestamp to the exported WXR filename?

Tags: export, timestamp

I have no working code example for this, so I'm hoping to not get blasted for an an inappropriate question...

Being able to add append a timestamp to WP xml exports (WXR) would be useful.

I assume it's possible, so where might I begin?

I want to get the datestamp that forms part of the filename to also include the time (rather than just the year/month/day).

Comment: Do you mean a timestamp in the filename created, or a timestamp within the xml structure itself?

Comment: @C C Thanks... Sorry, poorly worded question - now updated for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to do that, it's already there (if I understand the question correctly):

- In the *WXR* file we get a timestamp like:

  that's generated with:

  ```
  <?php the_generator( 'export' ); ?>
  ```

  that calls `get_the_generator()` where the *export* case is:

  ```
  $gen = '<!-- generator="WordPress/' . get_bloginfo_rss('version') 
      . '" created="'. date('Y-m-d H:i') . '" -->';
  ```

  It's possible to modify it or append to it via the  `get_the_generator_export` filter.
- Additionally the timestamp is added to the xml document with:

  ```
  <channel>
      ...
      <pubDate><?php echo date( 'D, d M Y H:i:s +0000' ); ?></pubDate>
  ```
- The generated export filename also contains a datestamp:

  ```
  $wp_filename = $sitename . 'wordpress.' . $date . '.xml';
  ```

### Update

To modify the exported filename, one can use this filter:

```
/**
 * Filters the export filename.
 *
 * @since 4.4.0
 *
 * @param string $wp_filename The name of the file for download.
 * @param string $sitename    The site name.
 * @param string $date        Today's date, formatted.
 */
 $filename = apply_filters( 'export_wp_filename', $wp_filename, $sitename, $date );
```

**Example:**

Here we add the `\TH-i-s` part to the filename:

```
add_filter( 'export_wp_filename', function( $wp_filename, $sitename, $date )
{
    return sprintf( 
        '%swordpress.%s.xml',
        $sitename, 
        date( 'Y-m-d\TH-i-s' )
    );

}, 10, 3 );
```

This will generate a filename like:

```
sitename.wordpress.2016-10-22T19-26-07.xml
```

This will avoid a possible confusing download series like this one:

```
sitename.wordpress.2016-10-22.xml
sitename.wordpress.2016-10-22 (1).xml
sitename.wordpress.2016-10-22 (2).xml
sitename.wordpress.2016-10-22 (3).xml
...
```

Hope you can adjust this to your needs!

Comment: thanks. Sorry, poorly worded question - now updated for clarity.

Comment: I updated the answer @gulliver

Comment: Thanks. Appreciated. It improves the default WP timestamp, by providing immediate visual info on time-of-creation. Better than my previous situation of confusion when multiple exports are done on the same day.

Comment: I agree with you, that it's annoying to have the `sitename.wordpress.2016-10-22.xml` and then `sitename.wordpress.2016-10-22 (1).xml` and `sitename.wordpress.2016-10-22(2).xml` etc for downloads the same day @gulliver